# Plotting function in terms of y and z, pgfplots floating point error

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following graph, given in terms of *y* and *z*, that I'm attempting to plot using `pgfplots`.  When doing so, it's giving me a "could not parse as a floating point number" error.

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                width=\textwidth,
                height=4in
                ]
                \addplot3[
                mesh,
                samples=21,
                restrict y to domain=-8:8,
                restrict z to domain=0:10
                ]
                {3*1000*5^2*z/(2*3.1415*(5^2+y^2+z^2)^2.5)};
                \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My searches online have led me to think it might be a continuity issue, which I don't believe is the case here (no way to get division by zero, and the plot value should decrease as *y* and *z* increase).  Other than that, the error log isn't giving me much to go on.

The plot should look something like that below, which was generated in Mathcad.  Any ideas on how to get this to plot?

[image: plot example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final answer, thanks to @Jake help:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
%\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\textwidth,
        height=4in,
        %view = {25}{-20},
        axis equal image, 
        ylabel = Lateral Distance ($y$),
        ylabel style = sloped,
        zlabel = Depth ($z$),
        z buffer = sort, 
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,  %shader=interp,
            samples=21,
            domain = -8:8, y domain = 0:10, 
            point meta = x, 
            % restrict y to domain=-8:8,
            % restrict z to domain=0:10
            ] 
            (3*1000*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5), x, y);
        \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### previous partial answers

I have no time to dig into the manual, but the normal 3dplots are made like a f(x,y). So if you use:

```
\begin{axis}[%
            width=\textwidth,
            height=4in
            ]
            \addplot3[
            mesh,
            samples=21,
            domain = -8:8, y domain = 0:10, 
            % restrict y to domain=-8:8,
            % restrict z to domain=0:10
            ]
            {3*1000*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5)};
            \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
        \end{axis}
```

You will have an output like this:

[image]

Notice that x, z , y are simple placeholders, so you can name thing in the graph how you like. For example,
with a bit of manipulation, and thanks to the comments from @Jake, you can have something like this

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
%\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\textwidth,
        height=4in,
        view = {25}{-20},
        ylabel = Lateral Distance ($y$),
        zlabel = Depth ($z$),
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,  %shader=interp,
            samples=21,
            domain = -8:8, y domain = 0:10, 
            point meta = x, 
            axis equal image, 
            % restrict y to domain=-8:8,
            % restrict z to domain=0:10
            ] 
            (3*1000*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5), x, y);
        \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I did notice that that worked.  If there's a way to rotate the graph such that the plot would be against the vertical face (where the Y-Z plane would be), that's a possible solution.

Comment: If you specify the function in the form `\addplot [...] (<x expr>, <y expr>, <z expr>);`, you get a rotated plot: `({3*1000*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5)}, x, y);`.
Note that you should also set `point meta=x` in this case, so the colour of the plot depends on the correct dimension; and you might want to set `axis equal image` so the axes all have the same scale.

Comment: @Jake, thanks, that's pretty close to ideal.  If there's no way to natively display it in terms of `y` and `z`, this will probably be my solution.

Comment: @grfrazee You can rename the variables using `variable=x, variable y=z`, so you can use your original equation, but you still need to use the form `(<x expr>, <y expr>, <z expr>);`: `({3*1000*5^2*z/(2*3.1415*(5^2+y^2+z^2)^2.5)}, y, z);`

Comment: @Rmano: You should set `z buffer=sort`, otherwise the plot is inverted

Comment: @Jake tried it (and surely you're right) but I can't see any difference...

Comment: @Rmano: You're right, that option doesn't seem to help in this case. However, if you remove the `view={25}{-20}` option and move the `axis equal image` to the `axis` options, the plot is no longer inverted and correctly scaled

Answer (score 1):

If you replace every y,z by x,y in your MWE, it works just fine.

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                width=\textwidth,
                height=4in
                ]
                \addplot3[
                mesh,
                samples=21,
                restrict x to domain=-8:8,
                restrict y to domain=0:10
                ]
                {3*1000*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5)};
                \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thanks, but see the answer above.